# Magento admin menu not working - dropdown not reacting

Tags: magento

My admin menu in the backend is not exploding anymore. I've already gone through all the file permissions in the /js/ folder but with no luck.

The problem startet when I deactivated an module from the backend.

My firebug/firefox calls this errors:

```
TypeError: this.element.setAttribute is not a function
element.attachEvent("on" + actualEventName, responder);
prototype.js (linje 4536)

NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]
null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
prototype.js (linje 1724)

TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
element.attachEvent("on" + actualEventName, responder);
prototype.js (linje 4536)

TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
element.dispatchEvent(event);
prototype.js (linje 4619)

NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]
Selector._div.querySelector(this.expression);
prototype.js (linje 3222)

NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]
null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
prototype.js (linje 1724)

NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]
null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with a module I disabled. It broke the admin menu, had to re-enable the module from the database to make it work again. It was mgt_amazingwysiwyg (If anyone wants to know)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you installed a new module. Magento's admin nav bar is based on JS so any Js errors and it will completely break down. You will have to work your way through the JS code and sort out these errors to have it working again. Also clear our cached JS files from /media/js directory.